# upgrade to VirtualCenter 2.5 U6 from U4 stopped VirtualCenter Server, why?

Tags: vmware-esx, vmware-vsphere, vmware-vcenter

Yesterday upon trying to upgrade VirtualCenter 2.5 from U4 to U6, the result was that the VirtualCenter Server service refused to start, showing the famous error 2.
I added the SQL Express dependency but this did not work, and I had to roll back to the previous night's backup.
I did not receive any error messages during the process.
Should I do U4 to U5, then U5 to U6??
So far as I could tell I followed the instructions correctly, I chose to keep the existing database.
Thank you, Tom 
I'm running esx3.5

Comment: It pains me to admit it but VMWares upgrade routines across the board are very poor. In most cases, rebuilding the item to the latest patch level is often an easier route.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recently had to upgrade our VC2.5 server as well -- unfortunately i came across several issues and landed up having to rebuild the entire system, reinstalling everything from scratch.

Turned out to be a giant pain in the ass, i lost all my resource pools... :(

If i were you i'd do U4 to U5, then to U6, and hopefully that will work out.

On a side note -- We run a system of about 50-60 Virtuals powered on 3 ESX 3.5 machines, and we removed the SQL Express component and installed MsSQL 2005 full.  VirtualCenter 2.5  showed a night-and-day performance difference, Everything is significantly faster now and all previous complaints were nullified.

Comment: A side-note on this: vCenter requires immense amount of RAM to properly function. The upgrade from 3.5 to 4.0 forced me into upgrading our small infrastructure server from 2GB to 4GB.

Comment: Good to know in the future -- our system happens to have 4GB of ram in it at the moment, but when this server retires i wouldn't have thought to put that much memory in it.